# Need a cheap hostel in Berlin - how much should I expect to pay?

Tags: budget, germany, hostels, berlin

I'm planning to visit Berlin. I'd like to stay in hostel and pay as little as possible. £10 would be an acceptable price, but £20 would be definitely over my budget.

So, can I expect to find something about £10, or at least not more than £15, when I just arrive to Berlin without pre-booking? Or is pre-booking the only option? I've found some hostel offers, but they require pre-paid via credit card, which I do not have.

Comment: I stayed at Baxpax mitre (more of a party hostel) and at east seven (relaxed and quiet) bother were sub £10 per night. Also Berlin is a quite a big city so make sure the accommodation is fairly central and close to a U or S ban

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to Hostelbookers (generally a bit cheaper than Hostelworld) and search by price, [shared dorm rooms start around a little over 6 quid](http://www.hostelbookers.com/results/loc/dd/dst/1002/arr/2012-08-07/ngt/2/ppl/1/#/rating_min=0/rating_max=100/price_min=0/price_max=108/shared=true/private=true/hos=true/hot=true/apt=true/cam=true/gue=true/suburb=/campaign=false/table_sort=shared_asc).  In the high season when I was there last year it was still possible to walk into some hostels and get a bed, but not guaranteed, especially around weekends when more people travel and use them.

Answer (score 7):

It depends a little bit of the month you want to travel to Berlin, but a bed in a dorm you can get from approximately 5£. In almost all hostels, it is not necessary to pre-book a bed. You can just walk there and see if one is available. However, during the high season it might be a good idea to pre-book at least the day before, or to show up not to late in the evening to ensure that there is a free bed for you.

You could for example check [hostelworld.com and then sort the accommodations by price.](http://www.hostelworld.com/search?search_keywords=Berlin,%20Germany&country=Germany&city=Berlin)